# latex \part{} displayed two times in toc

Tags: latex

I learned to edit the display of a `\part{}` in LaTex recently and it looks great when I generate a pdf but I have a problem in my table of content.

While a `\part*{}` is displayed one time, a `\part{}` is displayed two times in my toc.

For example, if I type

```
\part{Here is a part}
```

I will get this in my toc :

```
1. Here is a part    5

Here is a part       6
```

The right page number is the second one (6 in this case), but I would like to still have the 1. when displayed in the toc. Here is my code for my part definition

```
% --------------------------------------------------
% Paramétrage des parties
% --------------------------------------------------
\titleclass{\part}{straight}
\titleformat{\part}[frame]
    {\cleardoublepage\null\vspace{.10\textheight}\normalfont}
    {\filright
    \enspace PARTIE~\thepart\enspace}
    {8pt}
    {\huge\bfseries\filcenter\textsc}

\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{*0}{*5}

\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}
```

Could you tell me what is wrong in my code ?

Thank you very much in advance ! :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
(La)TeX-related questions are better asked at [tex.se]. Your question has been flagged so that it gets migrated there.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I thought that the 'latex' label was enough to send it to the good place. I'll create my question in the appropriate category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't exactly tell you why, but it is the `\cleardoublepage` in your definition that messes things up here - the following should work fine:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}

%\titleclass{\part}{straight}
\titleformat{\part}[frame]
    {\null\vspace{.10\textheight}\normalfont}
%   {\cleardoublepage\null\vspace{.10\textheight}\normalfont}
    {\filright
    \enspace PARTIE~\thepart\enspace}
    {8pt}
    {\huge\bfseries\filcenter\textsc}

%\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{*0}{*5}


% Comment the following to have chapters numbered without interruption (numbering through parts)
\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother%

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \part{First part}
        \chapter{First chapter}
        \chapter{Second chapter}
        %...
        \chapter{Last chapter}
    \part{Second part}
        \chapter{First chapter}
        \chapter{Second chapter}
        %...
        \chapter{Last chapter}
    \part{Last part}
        \chapter{First chapter}
        \chapter{Second chapter}
        %...
        \chapter{Last chapter}
\end{document}
```

In order to not let `\part` take up the whole page, but have it placed near the top of the page (with some spacing), use the following where `\titleclass{\part}{top}` sets part to behave like chapter:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}

\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[frame]
    {\normalfont}
    {\filright
    \enspace PARTIE~\thepart\enspace}
    {8pt}
    {\huge\bfseries\filcenter\textsc}

%\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{*0}{*5}

% Comment the following to have chapters numbered without interruption (numbering through parts)
\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother%

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \part{First part}
        \lipsum
    \part{Second part}
    \part{Last part}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I've been asked to write my text just after a \part{} on the same page and not a page after. I found out that \cleardoublepage was doing it. Is there another way to have my text written just after a new part ?

Comment: @Berhthun that's a misconception - in your example it was the `\titleclass{\part}{straight}` that was allowing the text right under the heading. i'd recommend using `\titleclass{\part}{top}` to get automatic spacing and parts always starting on a new page - see second example in my edited answer.